# Reversing a legacy DB in MDriven, undocumented errror

Tags: mdriven

What is the correct action to take for solving the error "[image], this occurred after "pressing play" with persistency towards a legacy db (read only access)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though one - very little to go on. Maybe your association end requires 2 attributes but the primary key of the target only has 1 attribute marked as key.

Try to downscale your model until it works - then slowly add things back. See if that process helps you to understand the error message better.